# Conditional Formatting Based on text and percent criteria

Tags: excel

I am trying to figure out how to create a conditional format that will look at the percentage in my field along with if there is text to determine the way the cell is formatted.

To begin I have a formula which determines based on the percentage if it should show a `"/"` and a number or not. Example below...

```
=IF(AND(E$21>0,E$21<0.9),(CONCATENATE(TEXT(E$21,"0%")," / ",(ROUND(E$23,2)))),E$21)
```

The current conditional format is below...

`=IF(OR(ISTEXT(AM9),AM9=0),1,0)`

And in the OTS Summary picture below you can see this will show the percentage / number in the summary and color it red. I want to update the yellow the same way, but when I input the formula to the yellow it turns the cell white.

[image: OTS Summary]

Comment: What formula are you using for the yellow category? It would be better to nest an additional if statement so you effectively end up with if(if statement 1 = true, yellow, if statement 2 = true, red, if statement 3 = true,green,false)

Comment: The current format for yellow is just a between .9 and .975. Can you give me an example of how you would adjust the yellow conditional format to recognize when it is in that percentile range to include the / number?

Answer (score 0):

In the conditional formatting menu, you can add several options to the same cell.
I would suggest something like `=IF(NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(E7,3))<0.975,TRUE,FALSE)`
Where E7 is your cell that you want to format with the conditional formattting.
eg you would have the `<0.975` part for you green value, then you could say `<0.9`for yellow, and `<0.5` for red (or whatever you want to do...